# Can't access my wireless router admin console through 192.168.1.1?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, setup

I do remember I was able to access it before. Then I was setting it up as a secondary router and I changed the default address to 192.168.0.3. Now I cannot access it neither through the default 192.168.1.1 or the address I have setup 192.168.0.3. The router in question Linksys WRT 54 GL.

I followed advice from [here](https://www.lifewire.com/linksys-wrt54gl-default-password-2624677) to find the router's new address by looking at default gateway when you are connected to the router via UTP cable. However I have not gateway set in such a scenario.

Comment: When that happens to me (not an uncommon occurrence), I do a hardware reset of the router and set it up again, This is normally successful.

Comment: You state that you were setting up a secondary router. If you have two routers competing in the same subnet, you might have issues trying to reach devices. Can you unplug everything from your secondary router, and just plug in a computer by itself into one of the LAN ports? This should isolate the router from anything else. If the router still has DHCP turned on, your computer should get an IP address from it, and you can use "ipconfig -a" in a CMD prompt to see your DHCP server, that is your router's IP. If you do not get a DHCP address, you'll need to set a static IP on your computer.

Comment: oof, throw that thing away. Get something at least n-speed. These routers had their hayday, you can find newer DD-WRT/openwrt routers on eBay for a couple bucks that will put that router to shame.

Comment: @Jim Diroff II do you setup the static for your computer or for the router? I did isolate the router even before.

Comment: Set a static on your computer, if the router is not giving out DHCP. DHCP from the router assigns an address to your PC, without that protocol running, you have to set static IPs on the clients. Routers have a static IP configured by default.

Comment: Ok, how do you access this static IP?